# Find module in anaconda for ipython

Tags: python, installation, ipython

I"m in window and trying to use pyodbc with ipython , I did

```
pip install pyodbc
```

and I am able to see the package and pyodbc.py under this location ..

```
C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\connectors\pyodbc.py
```

but when I tried to do

import pyodbc

```
ImportError : No module named pyodbc
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably not in the anconda environment.
Try

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

This will tell you where the current python environment looks for packages. I'm not familar with Windows, but in Linux, the anaconda bin folder needs to be prepended to the shell's PATH environment variable.

A temporary(?) hack is:

```
sys.path.append("C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages")
```